# When can you subtract cardinals? Does $|A|+|C|=|B|+|C|>|C|$ imply $|A|=|B|$ in ZF?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Suppose that $|A|+|C|=|B|+|C|$, and that both sides are strictly larger than $|C|$. Does this imply $|A|=|B|$ in the absence of the axiom of choice?

With choice, cardinals are totally ordered, and $\kappa_1+\kappa_2=\max\{\kappa_1,\kappa_2\}$ for infinite cardinals, so this is trivial. But I worry that things might go wrong when choice is not present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, of course not.

Suppose that $A$ is an infinite Dedekind-finite set and let $B=A\cup\{A\}$, then $|A|<|B|$. Now, let $C=\omega$, then $|A|+\aleph_0=|A|+(1+\aleph_0)=(|A|+1|)+\aleph_0=|B|+\aleph_0$.

Since $A\cup\omega$ contains a Dedekind-finite subset, it must be greater in cardinality than $\aleph_0$, so your condition is satisfied.

---

More generally, this would be equivalent to the axiom of choice. To see that, let $U$ be any set which cannot be well-ordered and let $\kappa$ be $\aleph(U)$, the Hartogs number of $U$.

Then consider $A=U+\kappa$ and $B=U+\kappa^+$, and let $C=\kappa^{++}$, the argument goes as in the above case. Then the only way that we fail the required condition is that $|C|\nless|A|+|C|=|B|+|C|$, in which case $A$ can be well-ordered.

Comment: Yeah I figured infinite Dedekind-finite sets would ruin my day but I hadn't put together how. Thanks!

Comment: So it seems to me that "cardinal subtraction" is entirely unsalvageable without the axiom of choice EDIT: I suppose this still works in the case of well-orderable sets. That is, if $\kappa_1>\kappa_2$ are both well-orderable infinite cardinals then $\kappa_1-\kappa_2$ can be defined to be $\kappa_1$.

Comment: Yes, to both. But in the latter case it's kinda stupid and it's still not cancellable without the condition on $C$ being "small".

Answer (score 5):

To complement Asaf's answer, let me mention that there are some interesting $\mathsf{ZF}$ theorems showing that in various cases (not just the well-ordered context) we have a well defined subtraction operation. (The subtraction $\frak x-\frak y$ of cardinals is defined
if and only if there is a unique cardinal $\frak z$ such that $\frak
y+\frak z=\frak x$, in which case $\frak x-\frak y$ is defined as
$\frak z$.)

The best known result in this regard is due to Lindenbaum and Tarski. They claimed in 1926 that (provably without choice) $2^{\frak a} - {\frak a} = 2^{\frak a}$ for all cardinals ${\frak a}\ge\aleph_0$. The first published proof is due to W. Sierpiński in 1947 ("Démonstration de l'égalité $2^{\frak m}-{\frak m}=2^{\frak m}$ pour les nombres cardinaux transfinis", Fund. Math. **34** (1947), 113–118; [MR0023315](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=23315); "Sur la différence de deux nombres cardinaux", Fund. Math. **34** (1947), 119–126; [MR0023316]](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=23316)).

The  recent paper by Guozhen Shen "Remarks on infinite factorials and cardinal subtraction in $\mathsf{ZF}$", MLQ Math. Log. Q. **68** (2022), no. 1, 67–73, [MR4413645](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=4413645), shows that, provably in $\mathsf{ZF}$, for all cardinals $\mathfrak a$, if $\aleph_0\le 2^{\mathfrak a}$ and there is a permutation without fixed points on a set of cardinality $\mathfrak a$, then
${\mathfrak a}!-{\mathfrak a} = {\mathfrak a}!$. (As Shen points out in the comments) the paper also proves that for all cardinals $\mathfrak a,\mathfrak b$, if $\aleph_0\le2^{\mathfrak a}$ and $\mathfrak b\le^* \mathfrak a$ (meaning that there is a surjection from a subset of $\mathfrak a$ onto $\mathfrak b$), then $2^{\mathfrak a}-\mathfrak b=2^{\mathfrak a}$.

Comment: Thanks! That is a complement. Interesting stuff.

Comment: `\frak x` is $\frak x$, `\frak y` is $\frak y$, and `\frak z` is $\frak z$?? Wild.

Comment: There might not be permutations without fixed points on a set of cardinality ${\frak a}\ne 1$? That's wild! (Is this all infinite Dedekind-finite sets?)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Yes, that is consistent, e.g. in Cohen's model the canonical Dedekind-finite set, or in general a strongly amorphous set. On the other hand, it is consistent that a Dedekind-finite set can be partitioned into pairs (e.g. a Russell set, or a $2$-amorphous set), in which case, switching the element of each pair is a permutation without fixed points.

Comment: My paper cited also gives a generalization of Lindenbaum and Tarski's result: For all cardinals $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$, if $\aleph_0\leq2^\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}\leq^\ast\mathfrak{a}$, then $2^\mathfrak{a}-\mathfrak{b}=2^\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: @Guozhen Thanks, yes! I added the result to the text of the answer.