# Inequality Regarding Subtraction of Transfinite Cardinals. Is this correct? $\aleph_0 - \aleph_0 \le \aleph_0$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I've been learning about transfinite cardinals and examining the expression $\aleph_0 - \aleph_0$. I've read online that subtraction in this case is not defined because it can result in any finite cardinal as well as $\aleph_0$.

However, **is it reasonable to simply say that $\aleph_0 - \aleph_0 \le \aleph_0$?**

If not, why not? Thanks!

EDIT: I have seen texts write $\aleph_0 - n = \aleph_0$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, which makes sense. So then it appears subtraction is defined between a transfinite cardinal and finite cardinal but not on two transfinite cardinals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtraction of cardinals is defined only when the result is unique: If $\kappa,\lambda$ are cardinals, and there is a unique cardinal $\mu$ such that $\lambda+\mu=\kappa$, then $\kappa-\lambda$ is defined, and its value is $\mu$. The notation is not very common, since the situations where the expression is well-defined are either uninteresting, or rare, depending on whether we assume the axiom of choice.

An example is the case you suggest: $\aleph_0-n=\aleph_0$, for any natural number $n$. Also, for transfinite cardinals (alephs) we have that $\kappa-\lambda$ is defined precisely when $\lambda<\kappa$, in which case $\kappa-\lambda=\kappa$.

A less trivial example is that $2^{\aleph_0}-\aleph_0=2^{\aleph_0}$. This is interesting in that the axiom of choice is not needed to verify it. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4725897/462) for other examples and references.

As for your question regarding $\aleph_0-\aleph_0\le\aleph_0$, I suppose you could define this expression in a way that is meaningful, even though $\aleph_0-\aleph_0$ by itself is not. I would take it to mean that whenever $A,B$ are countably infinite sets, with $B\subseteq A$, then $A\smallsetminus B$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of cardinal arithmetic, addition & multiplication can be well-defined on cardinals, without having to consider the particular underlying sets: if $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$ are sets such that $\alpha := |A_1| = |A_2|$ and $\beta := |B_1| = |B_2|$, then $$\alpha + \beta = |A_1 \sqcup B_1| = |A_2 \sqcup B_2|$$ and also $$\alpha \times \beta = |A_1 \times B_1| = |A_2 \times B_2|,$$ regardless of the particulars of the sets $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$. However, if we want to define subtraction in the "natural" way, $$\alpha - \beta = |A_1 - B_1| = |A_2 - B_2|,$$ it could easily happen that the cardinalities $|A_1 - B_1| \neq |A_2 - B_2|$, where $X - Y$ is the set of all elements of $X$ that don't also belong to $Y$. So subtraction is not well-defined on cardinalities (which are really equivalence classes of sets) in the same way that addition and multiplication are, and for similar reasons, division would also not be well-defined.

Comment: I do see why subtraction is not well defined, due to the fact that the definition of the underlying sets can alter the result. I acknowledge this in my OP. However, it seems like the inequality $\aleph_0 - \aleph_0 \le \aleph_0$ covers all such ambiguity and could potentially be useful in some applications. that is really what my post is about.

Comment: It is true that if $\vert A \vert = \aleph_0$ and $\vert B \vert = \aleph_0$ then $\vert A \setminus B \vert \leq \aleph_0$, so in that sense your inequality is expressing something correct.  However, it is highly misleading to write it as "$\aleph_0 -\aleph_0 \leq \aleph_0$" because writing that suggests that the expression "$\aleph_0 - \aleph_0$" makes sense, which it does not.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy In one sense your inequality is trivially true. Since $A - B \subseteq A$, of course the cardinalities satisfy $|A - B| \leq |A|$, regardless of the size of $|B|$. What other people are explaining to you is that it doesn't make sense to write $|A - B| = \aleph_0 - \aleph_0$, because that second expression is not well defined.

Comment: okay, i do see the point. i would hesitate to call it trivally true though. The fact one can remove a denumerable number of objects from a denumerable set and still be left with a denumerable set is not exactly obvious to the uninitiated. but i digress... I have seen texts write $\aleph_0 - n = \aleph_0$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, which makes sense. So then it appears subtraction is defined between a transfinite cardinal and a finite cardinal but not on two transfinite cardinals?

Comment: It's not trivially true that a subset ($A - B$) of a set ($A$) has at most as many elements as the original set did? That's all that's at work in a statement like $|A - B| \leq |A|$. If not trivial, at least it's quite elementary. A statement like $\aleph_0 - n = \aleph_0$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$ is different because the LHS of that equality *is* well defined: no matter what particular sets $|A| = \aleph_0, |B| = n$ we choose, $|A - B| = \aleph_0$ is going to be countably infinite.